# Javascript - Strip everything except that defined by a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to strip everything from a text box, except that which is defined by a regular expression, on each keyUp event?

For example, I have a text box and the regex `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`. Whenever the user enters (or pastes) characters, it will strip any characters that are not contained in that regular expression.

Comment: see: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/148144-regular-expression-check-string-alphanumeric-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regexp replace with a negated character class (I also abbreviated the character, made it case insensitive, and did a global replace)

```
var input = document.getElementById('sandbox');    
input.onkeyup = function(){
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/ig,'');
}
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/theprawn/GvbKY/

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```
<input />
```

Javascript:

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
input.onkeydown = function () {
 input.value = input.value.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g).join();
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/See9C/1/)